# SQL Server 2005: CASE statement question

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, case-expression

I have 4 bit values and a `varchar`

```
sku
a
b
c
d
```

From a `SELECT` statement I need to get the following result for each bit value that has a value of 1.

So for each bit value I need to output its actual name, so the result would look like:

```
"NameOfSKU, a, c"
```

In a comma delimited format.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: Why/how do you get "a, c" for "NameOfSKU" ?? Not very clear..... can you try and elaborate a bit more??

Comment: It's a case *expression* not a statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sku 
     + (CASE WHEN a=1 THEN ', a' END)
     + (CASE WHEN b=1 THEN ', b' END)
     + (CASE WHEN c=1 THEN ', c' END)
     + (CASE WHEN d=1 THEN ', d' END)
FROM someTable
```